# Argument '0' is out of range error

Tags: sql, oracle, arguments

I have a query (sql) to pull out a street name from a string. It's looking for the last occurrence of a digit, and then pulling the proceeding text as the street name. I keep getting the oracle

> "argument '0' is out of range"

error but I'm struggling to figure out how to fix it.

the part of the query in question is

```
substr(address,regexp_instr(address,'[[:digit:]]',1,regexp_count(address,'[[:digit:]]'))+2)
```

any help would be amazing. (using sql developer)

Comment: Maybe you address has no digits, so the count gives 0; can you please post an example of starting string and desired output?

Comment: that was exactly it. when i added a clause to make sure there were digits in the string, the error went away. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth parameter of [`regexp_instr`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions114.htm) is the occurrence:

> occurrence is a positive integer indicating which occurrence of
>   pattern in source_string Oracle should search for. The default is 1,
>   meaning that Oracle searches for the first occurrence of pattern.

In this case, if an address has no digits within, the `regexp_count` will return 0, that's not a valid occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution, which does not require separate treatment for addresses without a house number, is this:

```
with t (address) as (
       select '422 Hickory Str.' from dual union all 
       select 'One US Bank Plaza' from dual
     )
select regexp_substr(address, '\s*([^0-9]*)$', 1, 1, null, 1) as street from t;
```

The output looks like this:

```
STREET
-------------------------
Hickory Str.
One US Bank Plaza
```

The third argument to regexp_substr is the first of the three 1's. It means start the search at the first character of address. The second 1 means find the first occurrence of the search pattern. The null means no special match modifiers (such as case insensitive - nothing like that needed here). The last 1 means "return the first SUBEXPRESSION from the match pattern". Subexpressions are parts of the match expression enclosed in parentheses.

The match pattern has a $ at the end - meaning "anchor at the end of the input string" ($ means the end of the string). Then [...] means match any of the characters in square brackets, but the ^ in [^...] changes it to match any character OTHER THAN what is in the square brackets. 0-9 means all characters between 0 and 9; so [^0-9] means match any character(s) OTHER THAN digits, and the * after that means "any number of such characters" (between 0 and everything in the input string). \s is "blank space" - if there are any blank spaces following a possible number in the address, you don't want them included right at the beginning of the street name. The subexpression is just [^0-9]* meaning the non-digits, not including any spaces before them (because the \s* is outside the left parenthesis).

My example illustrates a potential problem though - sometimes an address does, in fact, have a "number" in it, but spelled out as a word instead of using digits. What I show is in fact a real-life address in my town.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> looking for the last occurrence of a digit, and then pulling the proceeding text as the street name

You could simply do:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( address, '^(.*)\d+\D*$', '\1' )
         AS street_name
FROM   address_table;
```